# get 16 equidistant points along the circumference of ellipse

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, ellipse

I am trying to get the 16 equidistant point on ellipse (equal arc length along the ellipse).

Using some research, I am able to get the angle from which I can get those point by drawing a straight line and getting the intersection point but unable to find the length of line to be drawn from the center. I have also explored https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172766/calculating-equidistant-points-around-an-ellipse-arc but getting confused in formula[image]

What is the value of φ here?

Can anyone please help me there on getting the points. Thanks

Comment: see [compute ellipse parametric angle for specific real angle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71219436/2521214) look for `ellipse_angle` in **[edit2]**  also see [evenly space circles along ellipse circumference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19560243/2521214)

Comment: This is called the *eccentric angle*, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

We can define (axis-aligned) ellipse parametrization as

```
x = a * cos(φ)
y = b * sin(φ)
```

where parameter `φ` has range `0..2*Pi`.

Resulting point `(x,y)` is situated at angle `θ` relative to the ellipse center. Your linked post shows formula for  `θ/φ` transformation.

Note - `θ` is real angle, `φ` is not!, it is just parameter.

You perhaps don't need `θ` here. To solve the problem, you have to find ellipse circumference length `L` using elliptic integral for `φ = 2*Pi` (numerically).

Then find `φ` values corresponding to arc length `L/16, 2*L/16...15*L/16` - numerically again, and calculate corresponding point coordinates from the parametrization equations.

Comment: no need to do this numerically ... I did it like that for years too but recently I came up with simple `O(1)` analytic solution see [float ellipse_angle(float rx,float ry,float ang)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71219436/2521214) at the end of my answer (edit2)  there is also slow numeric version before that ...

Comment: @Spektre Emm.. Seems your approach is intended for `t(or fi)-theta` transformation, but I wrote about numerical methods for equal arc length problem

Comment: ahhh now I see the `(equal arc length along the ellipse)` I probably stopped reading at `16 equidistant point` ...